# Router not automatically connecting to Internet via PPPoE

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I'm having a [D-Link Wireless AC750 Dual Band Router](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=677) connected to a cable modem using a network cable. The ISP connection is coming via an Optical fiber cable.

The problem is that the **router is not automatically connecting to the internet via the PPPoE mode.**

I always have to login to the router interface and click this Apply button. It will work fine after that.

[image: screenshot of the button]

I've tried:

1. Resetting the router
2. Changed the LAN IP Address

...but in vain. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot or resolve the issue:

1. We can try to set up the router using the automatic wizard， the result is the same problem?
2. Try to disconnect the router. We connect the computer directly to the modem to test if there is a problem with the modem. We can follow the method below.

[How to setup and use PPPoE internet connections in Windows 10](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-setup-and-use-pppoe-internet-connections-windows-10)

3. If there is no problem with the modem in step 2, in the case of the above settings, we connect our own mobile phone to the router, we test to see if the mobile phone will be disconnected?  If the phone is disconnected, there may be a problem with the router.
4. If there is no problem with the modem in step 2, in the case of the above settings, but change "**Set DNS Manually**" to "**Attain DNS Automatically**", then we connect our own mobile phone to the router, we test to see if the mobile phone will be disconnected? If the phone is disconnected, there may be a problem with the router.
5. If the test result is a problem with the router, let's check if it is a hardware problem or a software problem. If it is a software problem, we can try to refresh the latest firmware version.. If it is a hardware problem, we can go to the repair.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried connecting the modem directly to my PC, its fine. How can I connect it to the mobile phone? Its not having a USB port, did you mean by WiFi?

Comment: Yes, connect the mobile phone by wifi that router broadcasts, then view if mobile phone and laptop disconnect the wifi at the same time.

Comment: If internet comes or goes, its happening simultaneously via Wifi or LAN